Not the same result on PostgreSQL and in my JPA Springboot
I don't understand how is it possible.
In my DataGrip, i do this request :
select box_dr.id,
       case when tbox_dr.name is null then box_dr.name else tbox_dr.name end,
       case when tbox_dr.description is null then box_dr.description else tbox_dr.description end,
       case when tbox_dr.hint1 is null then box_dr.hint1 else tbox_dr.hint1 end,
       case when tbox_dr.hint2 is null then box_dr.hint2 else tbox_dr.hint2 end,
       case when tbox_dr.hint3 is null then box_dr.hint3 else tbox_dr.hint3 end,
       type,
       era,
       num
from box_door box_dr
         left join translate_box_door tbox_dr
                   on tbox_dr.box_id = box_dr.box_id
                       and tbox_dr.door_id = box_dr.id
                       and tbox_dr.locale = 'en'
where box_dr.box_id = 0
order by box_dr.id

The 3 first lines are correctly translate :

0,name en,"<p align=""justify"">
   A paragraph with <strong>strong</strong>, <em>emphasized</em>
   et du <span style=""color: red"">text coloré</span>.
</p>",hint 1 en,hint 2 en,hint 3 en
1,Story Step 1,This is a story !,hint 1 en,hint 2 en,hint 3 eb
2,Step 2,The TWO !,hint 1 en,hint 2 en,hint 3 eb

I thought it was my model, it's the only thing which is different :

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "box_door")
public class BoxDoorModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("box")
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "box_id")
    private BoxModel boxModel;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String hint1;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String hint2;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String hint3;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("nextBox")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "next_id", nullable = true)
    private BoxDoorModel nextBoxDoor;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BoxDoorType type;

    private int box_num;

    @NotNull
    @ColumnDefault("0.0")
    private Float maxPoints;
    @NotNull
    @ColumnDefault("0.0")
    private Float minPoints;

    @NotNull
    @ColumnDefault("2024")
    private int boxEra;


}


When i do the same request in my JPA in SpringBoot i got only 1st and 2nd line trnaslated, not the 3rd ..
@Query(value = "select box_dr.id, " +
       "case when tbox_dr.name is null then box_dr.name else tbox_dr.name end, " +
       "case when tbox_dr.description is null then box_dr.description else tbox_dr.description end, " +
       "case when tbox_dr.hint1 is null then box_dr.hint1 else tbox_dr.hint1 end, " +
       "case when tbox_dr.hint2 is null then box_dr.hint2 else tbox_dr.hint2 end, " +
       "case when tbox_dr.hint3 is null then box_dr.hint3 else tbox_dr.hint3 end, " +
       "type, " +
       "era, " +
       "num " +
"from box_door box_dr " +
         "left join translate_box_door tbox_dr " +
                   "on tbox_dr.box_id = box_dr.box_id " +
                       "and tbox_dr.door_id = box_dr.id " +
                       "and tbox_dr.locale = :locale " +
"where box_dr.box_id = :boxId " +
"order by box_dr.id",
            nativeQuery = true)
Optional<List<BoxDoorModel>> findAllDoorByBoxId(
            @Param("boxId") Integer boxId,
            @Param("locale") String locale)

When i evaluate my method, it return line 1 and 2 translated but not the other ..
Stranger thing, when i add order by box_dr.id, it keep only the first line translated.
I tried to keep my variable unused like and tbox_dr.locale = 'en' and where box_dr.box_id = 0  but nothing changes.
What am i missing or doing wrong ?
Thanks a lot

SOLVED
I used projection to solve my problem. this post helps me and removing my nativeQuery = true.
Thanks !


Do not use images for textual data. Copy and paste the output as text into the question text. 2) Are you sure you are connected to same database in both cases?


Hi, thanks for your answer, okay, no picture sorry ! 2) yes, i'm sure, i have only one database in local

I think my problem comes from my Entity, but i'm not sure. I think it's the only differences. So i updated my post

I wouldn't do any of this in a native query.  Load the entity as it is and let your getters decide what to return.  That said, it could be as simple as not defining the proper dialect.

Hi Lane, thanks. How can i do to load the entity as it and let my getters decide ?
